# Calculating Genetic Distance

Tags: dna, y-dna

Is the Genetic Distance between two Y-DNA STR test results simply the number of str values that do not match?

For example, if two people have the exact same values for all STR values except DYS413, then the Genetic Distance would be 1?

Again, if two people only differ on DYS481, with one having a value of 21 and the other having a value of 26, would the GD be again 1?

Are there other formulas for calculating Genetic Distances?

I have read that DYS464 is the most diverse marker.

Should the fact that one marker can be more diverse than another not have an impact on Genetic Distance calculations?